# Chunked Uploading in VSO

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc3HA.png)can anyone tell me how to upload files in chunk on VSO

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/attachments#chunked-upload
[Below is the code that I have wriiten but I am getting an exception in UpdateWorkItemAsync method ... Exception-:  {"TF237136: File attachment does not exist, or you do not have permissions to read it."}

Comment: That is used to upload file to work item as attachment. Do you want to upload files to version control or upload attachments?

Comment: I want to attach file to the wokitem but I am not getting how to specify the byte range of the chunk.

Comment: It will be huge help if you provide me implementation for that

Comment: What language you use? For C# there is a good example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.sendchunked(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am using c# for uploading file

Comment: Do you success uploading file with my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

1. Create a .net application (e.g. Console Application)
2. Install [Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) package

Code:

```
var u = new Uri("https://xxx.visualstudio.com");
VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "[PAT]"));
var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);
var workItemTracking = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
var attachement= workItemTracking.CreateAttachmentAsync("D:\\WebAPITest2.zip", "chunked").Result;
```

Comment: Above is the code that I have written but I am getting an exception while calling UpdateWorkItemAsync function Exception-: {"TF237136: File attachment does not exist, or you do not have permissions to read it."}

Answer (score 1):

```
 var u = new Uri("https://v-vabhan.visualstudio.com/");
VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, pad));
var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);
var workItemTracking = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();var attachment = workItemTracking.CreateAttachmentAsync("D:\\Area.xml","chunked").Result;
JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument();
patchDocument.Add(new JsonPatchOperation()
{
Operation = Operation.Add,
Path = "/relations/-",
Value = new
{
rel = "AttachedFile",
url = attachment.Url,
attributes = new 
{ 
comment = "VanDelay Industries - Spec" 
}
}
});
WorkItem result = workItemTracking.UpdateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, id).Result;
Console.WriteLine("Done attachment.........."+result.Url);
```